# Existence of a function in Radon Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, duality-theorems

I am having trouble to construct a function $f$ in the following problem.

Let $X$ be Locally Compact Hausdorff topological space. Let $\mu$ is a positive Radon measure on $X$ with $\mu(X)=\infty$ then there exists $f\in{C_{0}(X)}$ such that $\int_{X}fd\mu=\infty$.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $C_{0}(X)$ in this context?

Comment: The symbol $C_{0}(X)$  denotes the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $X$ (i.e. $f\in{C(X)}$) that vanish at infinity. And, an $f\in{C(X)}$ is said to vanishes at infinity if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for each $x\in {K^{c}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** First construct a sequence of compact sets $K_n\subset\subset K_{n+1}$, such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(K_n)=\infty.$$

Define $f_n\ge 0$ continuous to but equal to $1$ in $K_n$ and $0$ in $K_{n+1}^c$.

Then look for $f=\sum a_nf_n$, for suitable $a_n>0$, $\sum a_n<\infty$, so that $\int_X f\,d\mu=\infty$ and $f\in C_0$.

Comment: @ Yiorgos S. Smyrlis: Thanks! How do we guarantee that there exists a monotone increasing sequence of compact sets $K_{n}\subset{K_{n+1}}$ satisfying $\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\mu{(K_{n})}=\infty$?

Comment: @Algebra This is because of the inner regularity of the Radon measure $\mu$. Thus, $\mu(X)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset X,\ K\ \text{compact}\}$.